# App stops working after updating npm and node on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So I've made the big mistake of updating npm and node from versions 3.10.10 and 6.10.2, respectively to 5.6.0 and 9.3.0

Now my app doesn't work so I am getting quite desperate here. When I attempt to run it, I get the following error:

> /Users/me/Workspace/MyApp/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
>         throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
>         ^
>
> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (59)
>
> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3

I've looked up the error and haven't found much, except deleting the `node_modules` folder and doing `npm install`. Neither of which work. This now gives me the following error:

> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.8/node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.8 and node@9.3.0 (node-v59 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
>
> ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.c
>
> TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
>     CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3150000/sqlite3.o

I am not sure where to go from here but am not getting desperate. What is going on? Is there anything I can do or should I just reverse to a previous version of node and npm?

Comment: try running `npm rebuild`

Comment: *To close voters*, IMHO I don't think this is either a bad question nor is it too broad: the minimal but informative error log combined with STR point directly to `node-gyp`, which points to a C++ add-ons problem. A good number of node developers may never come across a package that uses C++ add-ons and have no idea how to debug it (or even that it's a thing at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run [`npm rebuild`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild), because Node-sass uses C++ addons, and that command

> runs the `npm build` command on the matched folders. This is useful when you install a new version of node, and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary.

There's probably also no reason not to update node-sass [to the current release 4.7.2](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases).

Have a look at another handy package called [`ncu`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) that can help you bulk-upgrade your `package.json`. Don't do it *carelessly*, you may create instability, but it's a handy start if you have a small number of specified dependencies.

Comment: I had done it previously one the newest version, but didn't seem to work. So I downgraded it and ran it, which now does work.